# Volume ray tracing using three.js without textures

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to visualize hydrogen wave functions, and would like to do this using volume ray tracing/casting. All guides online for creating volume rendering is based on having 2D textures from some medical imaging. In my case, I don't have any data as images, but instead the 3D data is already in memory ([I'm using them to generate particles right now](http://molecularorbitals.herokuapp.com)).

Do I really need to convert all my 3D data to 2D textures, only to load them in again, and fake a 3D texture? If not, how can it be done without textures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, from your link I understand that you have a function that takes a 3D coordinate and returns a propability between 0 and 1. You can use this directly during the evaluation of each ray.

```
For each ray, 
    for each distance ∆ along the ray
        calculate the coordinates at distance ∆ from the camera
        calculate the propability at those coordinates using your function
        add the probability to the ray's accumulated color
```

Using this method, you skip the particle positions that you have rendered in the linked example, and use the function directly.

Comment: Would love to see your results!